# How to write this query in PDO for and get all the three output in three different arrays

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have this sql query

```
SELECT COUNT( testRunID ) , platform, SUM( IF( STATUS = 'passed', 1, 0 ) ) passed_count, 
SUM( IF( STATUS = 'failed', 1, 0 ) ) failed_count, 
SUM( IF( STATUS = 'incomplete', 1, 0 ) ) incomplete_count
FROM tooldata
GROUP BY platform
ORDER BY platform
```

which I having trouble writing in pdo. And how I can have the output incomplete_count, failed_count, passed_count in three different arrays ?
Guys pls help me. I am very new to php and pdo.

Comment: Have you tried running this query on the server directly? because `SUM(STATUS = 'passed', 1, 0) passed_count` doesn't look valid to me.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I tried running this query on phpMyAdmin and i get the desired output

Comment: @satish: If the query is (according to you) not the problem, then why post the query, and not the PHP code?

Comment: I didn't get you ?

I wanna know how to write this in PDO form :(

Comment: Why you are asking the same question from different accounts?

Comment: @Satish: if the query works when executed directly, then you post something that works. At the same time, you say that it doesn't work when you execute it through PDO. Why not post that PHP code? obviously, that's where to look. Also: you want to know how to write this with PDO? Well, [RTFM](http://www.php.net/pdo), and learn it

Comment: Just noticed the tons of dupes through @YourCommonSense 's links. He has a point: Read the help section, don't spam with the same basic question over and over, and put some effort into it yourself first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should not be answering this but seeing so many duplicates I should give you the answer so that you won't be posting anymore - 
Do like this -

```
$status = 'failed';
$allTest = $conn->prepare('SELECT SUM( IF( STATUS = :status, 1, 0 ) ) passed_count FROM tooldata GROUP BY platform ORDER BY platform' );
$allTest->execute(array(':status' => $status));
```

and then repeat the same query for - `$status = 'passed'; $status = 'incomplete';`

Comment: But don't every repeat what you did this time.